# 1215 Can not add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

Larvel 5.6.3
PHP 7.2.10

I am getting this following error for `php artisan migrate:fresh`

```
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `videos` add constraint `videos_video_identified_by_foreign` foreign key (`video_identified_by`) references `users` (`id`))
```

user table migation file -> `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table`
videos table migration file -> `2018_12_02_122553_create_videos_table`

Normally it happens when parent table is not existing and we are using its column as foreign key in our table, but as it can be seen users table should be created first and then videos table will be created, then why I am getting this error.

**users table**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**videos**

```
 Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('video_id');
    $table->text('video_link');
    $table->text('video_description');
    $table->string('video_category');
    $table->string('video_language');
    $table->unsignedInteger('video_identified_by');
    $table->timestamps();            
});

Schema::table('videos', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('video_identified_by')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Comment: Some time cache or sometime autoload files might result such issue, clear cache and run composer dumpautoload command.

Comment: @SagarGautam, thank you for your knid reply, I had  run `php artisan config:cache` and `composer dump-autoload` before running this command still I am getting this error.

Comment: is user.id a primary key?
is this constraint "videos_video_identified_by_foreign" already present?
I would advise you to thoroughly check your DB for any such things first.

Comment: I always have this problem when I try to set a key to a column with and a column without the keyword `UNSIGNED`

Comment: @MelroyFernandes Yes, users table is default laravel table and I have updatedmigration file code in question, please check it.

Comment: @KoenHollander I tried that too previously, gives some other errors, so I am trying to use that.

Comment: Are both tables using the `InnoDB` engine?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes.

Comment: Is the `videos` table empty when you add the foreign key?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I am using php artisan migrate:fresh, so all tables are empty.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it is 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

hi try this is work fine for me

```
<?php
    $table->integer('video_identified_by')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('video_identified_by')->references('id')->on('user')
          ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');      
?>
```

then php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: ah you make change in your id in table video try this

Comment: I dont think this works for you when you reference to the non existant user table. `on('users')` will be correct

Comment: i put the code try it or  give me teamviewer id and password to fix it

Comment: ah yes i miss the s it s users try like that i edit the code

Answer (score 0):

ah you make change in your id in table video try this

```
     Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('video_link');
        $table->text('video_description');
        $table->string('video_category');
        $table->string('video_language');
        $table->integer('video_identified_by')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('video_identified_by')->references('id')->on('users')
          ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');   
        $table->timestamps();            
    });

    }
 public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('videos');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add onDelete Cascade and change unsignedInteger to unsigned

```
Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('video_id');
$table->text('video_link');
$table->text('video_description');
$table->string('video_category');
$table->string('video_language');
$table->unsigned('video_identified_by');
$table->timestamps();            
});

Schema::table('videos', function($table) {
$table->foreign('video_identified_by')->references('id')->on('users')- 
>onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Shikha, but if you will see the comments, I have already tried that.